# My break function isn't working and i dont know why its outside the loop

Tags: python

I am relatively new to code and have been messing around with some functions, i am currently using it for school work and have been practicing code for my course work, however when i tried to do this random code the break function was outside of the loop somehow but i dont know why, any ideas?

```
var=input("what name would you like to use?: ")
varf= len(var) + 1

def rep():
  for i in range(0, varf):
    print(var[:i])
    
  for x in range(0, varf):
    print(var[x:])
  
  repeat=input("Would you like to go again? Y/N: ")
  if repeat.upper() =="Y":
    rep()
  else:
    break
  
rep()
```

Comment: It's outside the loop because you put it there.  This of course doesn't work because `break` only has meaning inside a loop (because its meaning is to break the loop that it's inside).  You probably want to just remove the `else: break` entirely.

Comment: Alternatively, replace `def rep():` with `while True:`, and then `break` will do exactly what you want it to do (replace `rep()` inside the loop with `continue`).

Comment: Which loop, _specifically_, do you think the `break` should be treated as inside of? (You have two `for` loops in this code, but they each have only one line in their body).

Comment: In Python, due to the lack of tail call optimization, it's discouraged to use recursion for this example.  For this, the Pythonic pattern would be a while loop with a break.

Comment: Oh, and in python, recursive functions don't count as loops as far as `break` is concerned.

Comment: Notice that `break` is not a function but a Python keyword used to get immediately out of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you actually wanted to write goes as follows:

```
def rep():
  for i in range(0, varf):
    print(var[:i])
    
  for x in range(0, varf):
    print(var[x:])

while True: 
    var=input("what name would you like to use?: ")
    varf= len(var) + 1
    rep()
    repeat=input("Would you like to go again? Y/N: ")
    if repeat.upper() != "Y":
        break
```

Now the `break` statement is inside the `while True:` loop body and works as expected.

In your code you have just forgotten to put the user input into a `while True:` loop to be able to go for another round of user input.

Comment: what does the continue function do? how exactly does it make the function repeat?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with `continue`. Have updated my answer and removed it. `continue` statement forces the loop to restart from the beginning and can improve readability if used as I have used it. It can also be necessary if there is more code in the loop body which need to be skipped (is not the case in the code above).

Comment: The repeating of a block of code is done by specifying `while True:` which will repeat the block endlessly because `True` is always true. `break` helps to get out of the loop, `continue` helps to restart the loop code block (called loop body) with the first line after `while True:`. By the way: in Python the explanations are often given by the names of methods/functions/keywords/classes/..., so if you have good understanding of the English language you don't need additional explanations.

Comment: By the way: in Python the code block of a loop is the code with appropriate indentation. If you don't appropriate indent a line of code the not indented line of code will be considered as not belonging to the loop code block ( i.e. the loop body ).

Comment: ok thank you for the help and explenation